# Нарисовать текст по кругу

Tags: c#

Нужно нарисовать текст с закруглением на изображении, как здесь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую библиотеку `Drawing.image`. Через неё возможно сделать закругление, или проще рисовать каждую букву отдельно?

Заранее изветсно, что количество символов равно 7.

Comment: Что такое Drawing.Image? Дайте точную ссылку на библиотеку. / В WPF легко рисовать текст по любым кривым.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос: с какой технологией вы работаете? WPF, WinForms, что-то другое?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko AlexanderPetrov я же написал "нужно на фото нарисовать текст". Для рисования использую System.Drawing.image. Причём тут WPF и WinForms?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151457/6468198

Comment: В вопросе `Drawing.Image` - это неизвестно что. | `System.Drawing.Image` - это известно. Но это не библиотека, а класс. Относится напрямую к WinForms.